# Hide "desktop applications" from Windows Store

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store

One thing that I really hate is that the Windows Store in Windows 8 is full of applications which make you visit its website to download and install.

In my opinion those apps shouldn't be a part of Windows Store and is there any way to hide them in the results?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think there is any way. In fact, a Google search brought me to this question. The Windows Store is still in early days so I guess we just have to wait. If you see something as a desktop app, just skip it. Not many desktop apps are listed in the Store anyway, so I don't see it to be too big of an issue.

Comment: In the game section I almost only see Desktop application, try to select order by newest

Comment: I don't see any. Which country are you from?

Comment: Please see this screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dJfjo.png  Anyway it's Italy with English language too (Applicazione Desktop)

Comment: I think it is one rogue developer who has uploaded. Every app has the same icon (in the bottom left corner of the logo).

Comment: Same developer or not they are spamming the results. I hope Microsoft that care of this